# Anova with stratified Cox model

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, anova, survival, cox-model

I'd like to use `anova` to investigate which variables are important to my Cox model outcome.

I tried using `anova` from `{stats}` and `car` but it seems neither can handle `strata()` terms, which I have in my model.

I can't use `anova` from `rms` because I have `pspline()` terms in my model.

An ideal solution might be `anova.coxph` from `survival` if I can change from sequential testing to non-sequential (e.g., like a two-model ANOVA or something like `drop1()`). However I don't know if this is possible.

I thought about calculating the relevant statistics manually (something like [this] answer suggests [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58588833/why-do-i-get-an-error-in-anova-test-on-cox-models-in-r)). This is in theory fine but will take a little while to run through all my 50 variables and doesn't seem very elegant.

Are there any better suggestions for how this can be done?

Comment: Do you have a separate model for each stratum, or a single set of coefficient estimates that applies to all strata? If the latter, can you get a result by applying `vcov()` to the output of your `coxph` object? That should be a square matrix of dimension equal to the number of coefficients that you estimated. For example, try `dim(vcov(yourCOXPHmodel)))`.

Comment: I have only one model with the same coefficients for all, so the latter. `vcov()` works and indeed returns what you suggested (including the individual spline terms of those variables with `psplines()` too).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a coefficient covariance matrix, you can perform [Wald tests](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald_test) on the set of coefficients associated with each original predictor. Tests on multiple coefficients at once are sometimes called "[chunk tests](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/27429/28500)." The test is whether *any* of a set of coefficients differs from zero, taking the covariances among their estimates into account.

That's how the `anova()` function in Frank Harrell's [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) works. I believe that's also how the `Anova()` function in the [`car` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=car) works if you specify `type = "II"` and `test.statistic = "Wald"` in the function call.

If there's a glitch arising from the strata in the model or some problem with naming of variables, you could do this yourself by identifying the indices of each set of associated coefficients (e.g.: all coefficients for your spline; a main coefficient and all associated nonlinear and interaction terms) and doing the calculations with a simple program. The fundamental part of `anova()` in `rms` is in the first few lines of the code (type `rms:::anova.rms` at the R command prompt):

```
ava <- function(idx) {
        chisq <- coef[idx] %*% solvet(cov[idx, idx], coef[idx], 
            tol = tol)
        c(chisq, length(idx))
    }
```

The `idx` values are the indices of the coefficients in question, the `coef` are the corresponding point estimates (in the original log-hazard scale), and `cov` is the coefficient covariance matrix. The `solvet()` function is a version of the standard `solve()` function, adapted in the [`Hmisc` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=Hmisc) to allow for adjusting the tolerance for singularity. The `chisq` is the chi-square statistic.

This is straightforward for an unpenalized model. Then the Wald test is on that chi-square statistic, based on `length(idx)` degrees of freedom. It also works with robust coefficient covariance matrices. Frank Harrell's [`rms` package](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rms) uses the difference between the chi-square statistics and the corresponding degrees of freedom (the expected value under the null hypothesis) as a convenient summary of how much each predictor (including nonlinear and interaction terms) contributes to the model.

You need to make some choices with a penalized model, for example if the model includes `pspline()` terms. As [Therneau and Grambsch](https://www.springer.com/us/book/9780387987842) explain in Section 5.8, there are two approaches to estimating the coefficient covariance matrix, resulting in two separate reports of standard errors in the `summary()` of a `coxph` object, `se(coef)` and `se2`. The former is more conservative. The `vcov()` function on such a model returns the more conservative matrix from the `var` slot of the `coxph` object, which the `survival` package uses for significance tests. I think that the `rms` package effectively uses the `var2` matrix, as proposed by [Gray](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2290630). Make a choice of which coefficient covariance matrix to use. You then need to use the *effective* degrees of freedom from the model corrected for the penalization, rather than the number of associated coefficients, in the chi-square test.

You can use the *effective* degrees of freedom for likelihood-ratio tests comparing nested models when such tests are appropriate. They are *not* appropriate when the model uses robust covariance matrices. Robust models use the same point estimates based on maximizing partial likelihood and then adjust the covariance matrix to account for things like clustering. Likelihood-based comparisons thus wouldn't take that extra uncertainty into account. If your model involves robust covariance matrices then you need to use Wald tests instead. As Harrell says in Section 9.6 of his [RMS textbook](https://hbiostat.org/rms/), such "adjustments for heterogeneity and correlated observations are not available for score and LR statistics."

Comment: Thanks a million Ed. So manual calculation is the way to go. I'm implemeting the code now but one problem I foresee: `psplines()` with `df=4` gives me 4 degrees of freedom in the `DF` column (as expected) of the summary of the `cox.zph` output, however there are 12 individual coefficient for these variables, so using `length(idx)` will give me a different degrees of freedom. Why is the `summary` not counting all of the individual coefficients and instead returning the df used in `pspline()`?

Comment: Also Ed, could I not achieve the same goal here by using `anova(full_model, model_minus_one_variable)` and doing a likelihood ratio test, and seeing if the difference is statistically significant? This seems like an adequate solution

Comment: @JEDHK sorry, I forgot that you were working with penalized splines. Then the effective df is different from the number of coefficients. That affects likelihood-ratio tests, too. What I wrote applies strictly to unpenalized coefficients (e.g., the set of dummy coefficients associated with a multi-level categorical predictor, or the unpenalized coefficients of a restricted cubic spline). I'll edit to cover penalization later, when I get a chance.

Comment: I am truly grateful for your help Ed. Take your time. Finally though, I'd much appreciate clarification on the question of whether I can just run a full, a reduced model, and then calculate the appropriate statistics manually (difference in likelihood, difference in DF, chi squared) and calculate significance for my model variables that way. If that doesn't work, why not?

Comment: It seems my df will either by that returned the `cpx.zph` or that from the variance-covariance matrix. Whichever one of these we agree that it is, then do I not have all the appropriate quantities (likelihood in full and reduced model, df in both) to calculate the relevant statistics (i.e. p value for each predictor)?

Comment: @JEDHK if your model involves robust estimates then likelihood-based tests aren't appropriate; the likelihoods don't take that extra source of variability into account. Otherwise you can use the _effective_ degrees of freedom reported for the `coxph` models (should be the same as those reported by `cox.zph`) for comparisons of nested models. I expanded the answer to explain issues related to penalization and robust estimates.

Comment: I redid analysis `robust = FALSE` after a brief chat with Professor Harrell (https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/588757/robust-standard-errors-in-cox-survival-analysis?noredirect=1#comment1088576_588757). However, I'm still not sure what the best route here is. Without `psplines()` (i.e., in my initial model runs in the script) p-values hardly change with `robust` as true or false. However, the models further in the script with `psplines()` show drastic changes. I would love to be able to understand what this difference tells me. Maybe worth opening a new question?

Comment: @JEDHK this comes down to whether you need robust standard errors (SE). They are needed in some form if you have multiple events per individual or other clustering. They are important if a Cox model is mis-specified; see [Lin and Wei](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2290085). Differences between standard model and robust SE might indicate mis-specification. If you use robust standard errors then you can't use likelihood-ratio tests; the chunk Wald tests then can evaluate what different predictors contribute overall to the model.

Comment: Yeah I did quite some reading on robust SE but it is still not very clear to me whether my situations demands it. As I say, without splines the results are basically unchanged between robust/non-robust; after adding `psplines()`, the results diverge a lot more... I read Lin and Wei a couple of times, it's a bit hard for me and I still saw nothing in there that suggested to me I should use robust SE (but that could me due to my own ignorance...)

Comment: Oh, and additionally Ed, I am now attempting to do LR tests (as [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/31690/how-to-test-the-statistical-significance-for-categorical-variable-in-linear-regr) for each variable in the model for which I have a coefficient estimate. Those I used as strata terms I will not do LRTs for (though they will remain in both the full and reduced models as terms). I think this is correct but confirmation would be nice.

Comment: @JEDHK that’s OK if you are using regular standard errors. LRT are NOT OK if you are using robust standard errors. If you are reporting robust standard errors you must use Wald tests with the corresponding effective degrees of freedom.

Comment: Got it Ed! Thanks a lot. I might post another question about the comment above my previous one in this thread. Really curious to know what's going on there.